# Killing idle pooled connections

Tags: sql-server

On SQL Server, I'm trying to prevent connection from staying open. From [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/articles/show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords) I understand that `Connection Lifetime` allows a connection to stay alive for a certain period of time since it was opened.

Quote: `When a connection is returned to the pool, its creation time is compared with the current time...`

Is there a way to do something similar, but with connections who are idle? When they return to the pool they'd be allowed to live for X seconds until killing them, unless they're used again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection pool will automatically kill connections which haven't been used in a while.  There's no way to identify these from the SQL Server side with 100% accuracy without running the risk of the client application throwing error messages when it attempts to use the connection from the pool which it things should be open put is really closed.

What problem are you trying to solve for?

Comment: A webpage that doesn't close a connection. If the connection used is idle long enough - the page probably finished loading and forgot to close.

Comment: IIS will return the connection to the pool once the page load is completed automatically, even if the developer didn't close the connection manually.  When load on the website drops IIS will automatically terminate connections that it doesn't think that it needs automatically. It's best to leave this up to the application tier instead of trying to be smarter than it.  Are you seeing a problem or running out of threads or something?

Comment: On occasion I can't make a connection. The error message suggests this is because the pool is full. Was assuming a page where connection doesn't close, though couldn't find it.

Comment: Sounds like IIS just needs to allocate more connections to the pool and isn't able to do so, probably because you've hit the limit on the number of connections in the pool. Just increase the limit and you'll be good to go. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance

Comment: Not sure that will solve it, if the same connection is opened on different instances of the page then there are a lot of open connections

Comment: Connection pooling doesn't care what page the connection is from. As long as the connection string matches it'll all be the same pool.